# Adding a pandas column without creating a list

Tags: python, list, numpy, pandas

I have 2 datasets of more than 1million rows and I am analyzing it with pandas (therefore they both are `pd.Dataframe` and noted `df1` and `df2`). I need to do add a column to df1 depending on the value of df2. I used the python list, but it is incredibly slow. Any advice to be quicker ?

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

numObs = []
for line in np.array(df1):
    numObs.append([num for i,num,exp in df2 if i==line[0]][0])
df1['NumObs'] = pd.Series(np.array(numObs),index = df1.index)
```

Comment: You should explain how your data set looks like, and how you are adding this numobs (conditions,etc) . Instead of only code.

Comment: It looks like all you're doing is comparing the first column of `df2` with first column of `df1` is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

It's not so much that you are creating a list, but that you have a nested loop, taking you over all combinations of `df1` and `df2`.  Roughly

```
for line in np.array(df1):
    numObs.append([num for i,num,exp in df2 if i==line[0]][0])
```

expands to

```
for line in np.array(df1):
    for i, num, exp in df2:
         finds = []
         if i==line[0]:
            finds.append(num)
         numObs.append(finds[0])
```

Normally a list comprehension is faster than an explicit loop, but here you are throwing away most of what the inner loop finds.  Simply breaking from the inner loop when a match is found, could save a lot of time (depending on how far it has to iterate in df2 to find the match.

```
for line in np.array(df1):
    for i, num, exp in df2:
         finds = []
         if i==line[0]:
            numObs.append(num)
            break
```

I'm not that familiar with Pandas.  Is 'i' the row count, and 'num' the value?  So that if `line[0]` is 10, you want `df2[10]` (or some such expression)?  One way or other you are looking up values in `df2` based on the first 'column' of `df1`, right?